# How we can write a factorization formula for an expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a bit confused about writing factorization formula.

For example if we have $n^4-3n+2=(n-1)(n^3+bn^2+an-2)$, how we can write a factorization formula for it?

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: $n^4-3n+2\,?$ or $n^4-3a+2$

Comment: There are no such "formulas" to factorization. A good general approach is to  find factors of the constant terms (in this case +-1 and +-2) and see if substituting them into the equation gives you 0. Then by the remainder theorem, one of the factors in your polynomials will be $(n-k)$ where $f(k) = 0$. You can then use polynomial division to get the rest of the terms.

Read up on it [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-remainder-factor.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

Comment: Also I think the factorization in your question is incorrect. $(n-1)(n^3 + bn^2 + an -2) = n^4 + (b-1)n^3 + (a-b)n^2 + (-2-a)n + 2$.  

Unless of course $a = b = 1$ and you meant $n^4-3n+2$ in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have written is almost a factorization formula.  It is written in the form "$X = Y \cdot Z$", but the numbers $a$ and $b$ have been left for you to figure out.  As Gowrath has observed in a comment, $$ (n-1)(n^3+bn^2+an-2) = n^4 + (b-1)n^3 + (a-b)n^2 + (-2-a)n + 2  \text{,}  $$ and this is supposed to equal $n^4 - 3n + 2$.  Comparing each coefficient, we get the following system of equations for $a$ and $b$:  \begin{align}
    n^4 &: & 1 &= 1 \\
    n^3 &: & b-1 &= 0 \\
    n^2 &: & a-b &= 0 \\
    n^1 &: & -2-a &= -3 \\
    n^0 &: & 2 &= 2  \text{.}
\end{align}
The solution to this system is readily found: $a = b = 1$.  Therefore, the desired factorization formula is $$  n^4 - 3n + 2 = (n-1)(n^3+n^2+n-2)  \text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in $n=1$ shows that $n-1$ is a factor.

Long division produces
$$
\frac{n^4-3n+2}{n-1}=n^3+n^2+n-2
$$
The [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) says that the only rational roots of $n^3+n^2+n-2$ could be $\{-2,-1,1,2\}$. Since none of them are roots, and the polynomial is a cubic, there can be no rational factorization of $n^3+n^2+n-2$.